# Magento question？ How to loop add reviews in the table？

Tags: loops, magento, foreach, addition, review

I attempt through the circulation increase the commentary the data, has the following code

```
 $i=1;
    while($i<=2){
      $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
          ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
          ->setStatusId(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
          ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())
          ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
          ->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()))
          ->save();
      $i++;
    }
```

The result only joins a data, does not have my anticipated two data。
Request help！ Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but you can't use $variable twice in a method/loop.
Use the full Magento instanciation instead, ie: `Mage::getModel('module/model')`

Answer (score 0):

use Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection(); function for get all model data of particular module.